# Can I choose Onsen UI 1.2.2 beta in Monaca?

Tags: onsen-ui, monaca

Since there are a number of issues find in Onsen UI 1.2.1, we hope to build a new version with Onsen UI 1.2.2 Beta in Monaca, any one know how to make it? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Onsen UI 1.2.2 is not included in Monaca since it is not released yet. Nevertheless, you can include it manually. Just upload the [new Onsen UI 1.2.2 files](https://github.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/tree/1.2.2-beta/build) (just css and js) to Monaca and include them in the `index.html` of your project instead of the old ones.

A cleaner way would be to start a new Onsen UI Minimum Project in Monaca (or include Onsen UI component in your current project) and replace `components/monaca-onsenui` with the [new files in Onsen UI 's Github](https://github.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/tree/1.2.2-beta/build). But also notice that the Minimum Project includes `components/loader.js`, and this is the actual file where Monaca imports OnsenUI. At the very bottom of that file you can find the code for OnsenUI 1.2.1, so just replace it with the content of Onsen UI 1.2.2's [onsenui_all.min.js](https://github.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/blob/1.2.2-beta/build/js/onsenui_all.min.js).

I'm using the new features of Onsen UI 1.2.2 by just modifying the `loader.js` as explained. Hope it helps!